# Run Django and GRPC same application

Tags: python, django, grpc

I'm working on the Django rest framework project and I need to work with gRPC as well. But I don't know how to manage to run both HTTP server and gRPC server same time. Like in .NET it has option to listen both HTTP1 and HTTP2.

When I use command

```
python manage.py runserver
```

then gRPC doesn't work

and when I used

```
python manage.py grpcserver
```

then Rest API doesn't work

Is there any solution to this problem? Thanks.

I used packages: **djangorestframework** and **django-grpc**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it

I just created a new custom management command and run both of it

```py
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from subprocess import Popen
from sys import stdout, stdin, stderr
import time
import os
import signal


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Run all commands'
    commands = [
        'python manage.py grpcserver',
        'python manage.py runserver'
    ]

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        proc_list = []

        for command in self.commands:
            print("$ " + command)
            proc = Popen(command, shell=True, stdin=stdin,
                         stdout=stdout, stderr=stderr)
            proc_list.append(proc)

        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(10)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            for proc in proc_list:
                os.kill(proc.pid, signal.SIGKILL)
```

Comment: how to use it ?